# Tableau connection error with database

Tags: sql, database, tableau-api

I am facing the below error while connecting Tableau with oracle database.
below is the screenshot for reference :
[image]

please suggest steps to fix this.I am very new to Tableau and database things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that connection information with Oracle Database is correct, which includes host name, port name, username and password. Above this you should make sure your server is up and running